# How to find evenly divisible numbers?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

I was solving a small assignment from the Infytq Learning program, where I come across this hindrance. i can't seem to figure out the problem I'm having.

Given a queue.

I have to form a new queue of whole numbers from the given queue where the numbers in the queue are evenly
divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 10.

Here's what I have done so far. I'm currently getting empty queue.

```
class Queue {
      
    private int front;
    private int rear;
    private int maxSize;
    private int arr[];
      
    Queue(int maxSize) {
        this.front = 0;
        this.rear = -1;
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.arr = new int[this.maxSize];
    }
      
    public boolean isFull() {
        if (rear == maxSize - 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
            
    public boolean enqueue(int data) {
        if (isFull()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            arr[++rear] = data;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        if(isEmpty())
            System.out.println("Queue is empty!");
        else {
            for (int index = front; index <= rear; index++) {
                System.out.println(arr[index]);
            }
        }
    }
            
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (front > rear)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
            
    public int dequeue() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        } else {
            int data = arr[this.front];
            arr[front++] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            return data;
        }
    }

    public int getMaxSize() {
        return maxSize;
    }
}


class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        Queue queue = new Queue(7);
        queue.enqueue(13983);
        queue.enqueue(10080);
        queue.enqueue(7113);
        queue.enqueue(2520);
        queue.enqueue(2500);

        Queue outputQueue = findEvenlyDivisibleNumbers(queue);
            
        System.out.println("Evenly divisible numbers");
        outputQueue.display();

    }
      
    public static Queue findEvenlyDivisibleNumbers(Queue queue) {
        //Implement your code here and change the return value accordingly
        Queue nqueue = new Queue(queue.getMaxSize());
        boolean flag = true;
        while(!(queue.isEmpty())){
            int val = queue.dequeue();
            for(int i=2;i<=10;i++){
                if(val%i!=0){
                    flag=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag){
                nqueue.enqueue(val);
            }
        }
        return nqueue;
    }
}
```

Comment: my first guess would be that once you set `flag=false;` inside your loop, it never has a chance to become true again. (So if the first element you dequeue isn't divisible by 1-10 the flag will be false and stay false for every iteration, resulting in your empty result)  You probably need to move `boolean flag = true;` inside your while loop so that for every element you dequeue the initial value is reset to true.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you so much, it was a really silly mistake from my part.

Answer (score 0):

You should reset your `flag` to `true` before each iteration of your `while` loop (as you've been suggested already).

---

In order to avoid such issues, consider extracting the internal loop into a separate method. That will help avoiding nested loop breaking confusion:

```java
public static boolean isDivisible(int value) {
    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
        if (value % i > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

then simply use it while iterating over your queue:

```java
public static Queue findEvenlyDivisibleNumbers(Queue queue) {
    Queue nqueue = new Queue(queue.getMaxSize());
    while (!(queue.isEmpty())) {
        int value = queue.dequeue();
        if (isDivisible(value)) {
            nqueue.enqueue(value);
        }
    }
    return nqueue;
}
```